# python vtk: how to import QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget

Tags: python, vtk

In c++, QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget can be included.

For python vtk, I also want to import QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget, is it possible? How can I import QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot import QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget in Python because the Python bindings for VTK doesn't have that class (as of VTK 8.2.0). A quick grep doesn't find it anywhere in the VTK python package. I grepped `/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/vtk*` (which is where I have `python3-vtk` installed) recursively for `QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget` and `grep` didn't find anything.